# Trouble with JQuery in Rails 5

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have used JQuery in Rails 5 before and understand the issue with turbolinks. I want my #title object to change color via .animate() when it gets hovered over. Here is my js file:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
$('#title').hover(
    function(){
        $('#title').animate({'color': '#404a87'},400);
    },
    function(){
        $('#title').animate({'color': '#393939'},400);
    }
);
});
```

Here is the object I am attempting to alter:

```
<p id="title">SEABOLT DESIGN</p>
```

I can't get anything to work on this object. I think the JQuery just isn't working. Can someone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Aggred to the official documentation of [jquery.turbolinks](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks)

> Turbolinks then needs to be at the end because it has to be the last to install the click handler, so not to interfere with other scripts.

you have to organize your file like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
//= require_tree .
//
//= require turbolinks
```

And place your Javascript in a new file in *app/assets/javascripts/* path.